# How can I use Wget / Curl / Plowshare to download from 1fichier.com as a premium member?

Tags: download, wget, curl

How can I download files from 1fichier.com (I am a premium member) with the help of Wget / Curl / Plowshare (Plowdown) or other CLI / command line tool / script?

Comment: Here is something for Rapidshare, but it may work in your case too: http://www.g-loaded.eu/2007/09/15/use-wget-or-curl-to-download-from-rapidshare-premium/

Comment: Thx, meanwhile I have implemented it: https://gist.github.com/Konstantinusz/47d42a7cb9003e4c476d